# Zend_Paginator return as objects

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

Zend_Paginator returns results as a standard array but I need to make my results come back as an instance of a class, how do I do this?

For example, I want all news articles so would need my items to come back as an instance of News_Model_Article

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also create custom zend paginator adapter like:

```
class Application_Paginator_Adapter extends Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect
{

  public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
  {
    $this->_select->limit($itemCountPerPage, $offset);
    $rowset = $this->_select->getTable()->fetchAll($this->_select);

    $articleModels = array();
    foreach($rowset as $row) {
      $model = new News_Model_Article();
      $model->setTitle($row->article_title);
      ...........
      $articleModels[] = $model;
    }

    return $articleModels;
  }

}
```

Use it as below:

```
$adapter = new Application_Paginator_Adapter();
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

Comment: Great, I was looking for something like that. Does StackOverflow has answers to all my questions already? This is cool... One thing: would you call this new class Application_Paginator_Adapter in terms of name space. "Applcation_" or "My_"?

Answer (score 5):

Use the Db_Table Paginator, you can initiate it like this:

```
$table = new Your_Zend_DbTable(); // Asuming this has configured the $rowClass property
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($table->select());
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
```

Then you can loop the $paginator object and read the object properties.

Comment: You mean by extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract?

Comment: Yes, you need to extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract. In your custom Zend_Db_Table, you have to set $rowClass to the name of your custom Zend_Db_Table_Row

Comment: Maybe you should have shown the complete example. There's a lot of assumptions here.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a new feature, but if you use `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect`, you should get objects (`Zend_Db_Table_Row`) already.

Comment: Only if you implement Zend_Db_Table_Row, if you're using an ActiveRecord pattern you probably won't

Comment: I tested it already since I'm using it myself in a data migration. I don't have to implement anything. It works right away. You have to use `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect` and it works out of the box.